# Getting 401 Unauthorized after moving from .NET Core 2.x to .NET 6

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

Getting 401 Unauthorized after moving from .NET Core 2.x to .NET 6. Moved the code from the `Startup.cs` to `program.cs`.

Application compiles and deploys. I'm able to log in with my credentials, but once it starts making API calls, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

Any ideas on what I could be missing here?

```cs
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

try
{
    logger.Debug("init main");

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration; // allows both to access and to set up the config
    IWebHostEnvironment environment = builder.Environment;

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    //MEW
    builder.Services.Configure<AuthenticationOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Authentication"));
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<GraphApiHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationProvider, OnBehalfOfMsGraphAuthenticationProvider>();

    var context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
    var architectureFolder = (IntPtr.Size == 8) ? "64" : "32";
    context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"lib\\{architectureFolder}\\libwkhtmltox.dll"));

    builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
    builder.Services.AddTransient<INotificationHelper, NotificationHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IReportHelper, ReportHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<TemplateGenerator, TemplateGenerator>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IListOfValuesHelper, ListOfValuesHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IInventoryService, InventoryService>();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var authSettings = configuration.GetSection("MSAuthentication").Get<AuthenticationOptions>();
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidAudiences = new List<string> { authSettings.Audience, authSettings.Authority }
        };

        options.Authority = authSettings.Authority;
        options.Audience = authSettings.Audience;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;

        options.SaveToken = true;
    });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

    builder.Services.AddTransient<SubItemService>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<EstimationHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<InventoryHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<UploadCutsHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<CutsHelper>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IStorageService>(provider =>
        new StorageService(configuration.GetValue("AzureStorage:ConnectionString", "")));

    // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    builder.Host.UseNLog();

    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "_myAllowSpecificOrigins",
            policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("https://mysite-qa.azurewebsites.net")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins");

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //NLog: catch setup errors
    logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization()`